# How do you extend an Android class like DayPickerPagerAdapter which is in the android.widget package?

Tags: android, widget, subclass

I would like extend the DayPickerPagerAdapter module from the android.widget package. Is this possible?

What I am trying to do is to create my own DatePickerDialog (which I will also need to extend) where I can highlight multiple days as opposed to only having the selected day highlighted.

Will I have to just copy the source code of these android classes? If so, is that legal to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can technically extend these classes by creating your new class in the same package (create the folder structure to match the package that you're extending), meaning that you would create something like this:

`/src/main/java/android/widget/CustomDayPickerPagerAdapter.java`

...and this will allow you to extend the `DayPickerPagerAdapter` class, because it's package-private.

However, this is no guarantee that you'll be able to successfully manipulate the internals of the component in the way that you want, because much of the functionality is likely `private`, which would mean you're out of luck.

You can also, of course, copy the source code of these components, as you suggest. This is perfectly legal because the entire Android project is open-source (Apache 2.0 license).  The downside of this is having to periodically check for updates and bugfixes from upstream, and having to re-integrate them into your custom component.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Dmitry. I will try to make the extended class in the same package and keep you posted on how that goes. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure it will be worth copying the source code for the reasons you pointed out...